# how to increase jersey WS timeout

Tags: java, jersey

How do I increase the jersey WS timeout? It is waiting on a call which takes around 2 minutes. 
It is timing out at WS layer. Do I have to increase client timeout as well? What are the defaults for these?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the two methods [`setConnectTimeOut`](http://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html#setConnectTimeout%28java.lang.Integer%29) and the [`setReadTimeout`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html#setReadTimeout%28java.lang.Integer%29) on your `Client` instance. The documentation specifies that the default values for both are `null` and thus the timeouts infinite.

Comment: How do I increase server side timeout though?

Comment: Just to make sure the information is not lost, here is the updated link: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.1-ea/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html#setConnectTimeout(java.lang.Integer)

Answer (score 3):

Do make sure to set the [setReadTimeout](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html#setConnectTimeout%28java.lang.Integer%29) as per the need of your application as setting connection timeout would be partial job done.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and `ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT` property.

**Example :**

```
ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1000);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
```